# Timescales of physical and chemical equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

**Background**

When describing the behaviour of a reacting systems, we usually don't hesitate to apply property models to relate the local properties of each species. For example, in the case of a gas phase reaction, we might assume that
$$
P_a(\vec{x}) v_a(\vec{x}) = R_a T(\vec{x})
$$
...for each point $\vec{x}$ and species $a$.  Since these models describe the *equilibrium* behaviour of a substance, applying them implicitly assumes that each species is, at least locally, in physical equilibrium. On the other hand, we generally wouldn't take the system to be in a state of *chemical* equilibrium – doing so would make the problem unrealistic.

All of this makes sense so long as the relaxation time to come to physical equilibrium is very small relative to the relaxation time to come to chemical equilibrium.

**Question**

In a reacting system, why would we assume that the time scale for each species to come to "physical" equilibrium (such that its properties are related by a standard models like the ideal gas law) is much shorter than the time scale for the system to come to chemical equilibrium?

When I think about an ideal gas, I can imagine that the properties are tied to an underlying distribution of molecular speeds, and that the ideal gas law holds so long as the distribution maintains a particular shape. [Note that the continuum assumption allows me to say that each "point" has both well-defined macroscopic properties *and* enough underlying particles for statistical mechanics to remain relevant] Since chemical reactions selectively add/remove components of particular speeds, however, the molecular speed distribution must be continuously self-correcting (through collisions) to maintain physical equilibrium. The time scale on which this self-correction occurs would therefore be related to the mean time between collisions of the species in question.

For comparison, the time scale on which the chemical reactions occur (which is also the time scale on which the perturbations to the speed distributions of the individual species occur) would be related to the mean time between reactive species with appropriate energy.

Thus, I'd expect the time scales to be:

- For physical equilibrium, the mean time between collisions of like species
- For chemical equilibrium, the mean time between collisions of reactants with appropriate energy to react

These are both collision timescales – why aren't they more comparable? Is it just that we're used to considering scenarios where the reactions' activation energy is large enough relative to the system's temperature that only a very, very small percentage of collisions have appropriate energy to react?

Comment: Equilibrium physics doesn't have anything to say about the conditions before the equilibrium. Indeed, non-equilibrium systems are much more interesting. Some, like oscillating chemical reactions are easy to understand, others, like those walking around on two legs that have also invented physics, not so much. Unlike for equilibrium systems there is no general theory for non-equilibrium systems. One can find chemical reactions that are slow in comparison with the underlying movement of their molecules and then there are those that are fast. It all depends.